# What does Nusuk mean?

Tags: hadith, definitions

I saw this word written in your Haddiths but can't find the meaning of it:

The Prophet (p.b.u.h) said, "The first thing that we should do on this day of ours is to pray and then return to slaughter the sacrifice. So anyone who does so, he acted according to our Sunna (tradition), and whoever slaughtered the sacrifice before the prayer, it was just meat which he presented to his family and would not be considered as Nusuk." A person from the Ansar named Abu Burda bin Niyyar said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! I slaughtered the **Nusuk** (before the prayer) but I have a young shegoat which is better than an older sheep." The Prophet (ﷺ) I said, "Sacrifice it in lieu of the first, but it will be not sufficient (as a sacrifice) for anybody else after you." - Sahih al-Bukhari 965

Answer (score 1):

It means ritual. In this context it means the sacrifice on Eid al-Adha.